# Attenuation of Input Signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, simulation, current-measurement, power-electronics, proteus

Schematic
   ![enter image description here][1]

Simulation Model ![enter image description here][2]

**Sine Source Component Settings**
[image]

**Simulation Results**
[image]

My question is straight forward , the channel A (yellow color) in oscilloscope shows the voltage across R37 , 29 ohm Resistor  varies between -75mV and 75 peak voltages.
Output (Green Color) varies between 2.05 to 3.00 peak voltage

Can Someone explain why does these values do not match calculations

Comment: 5.08 - 4.97 = 0.1 Vpp for CHA, The problem is an offset from how your scope is configured, don't insult "EE People" when you are missing a straightforward thing like that

Comment: Channel A is connected at one side of shunt resistor  and channel B to the other .Once you invert channel B and add show A+B , you will get drop across shunt resistor.

Comment: Yes, but the offsets are likely in divisions and you have inconsistent V/div and offsets between the relevant channels

Comment: Even if I do not press A+B  , the waveform remain same . If you think the offset is due to position scope , changing it dose not solve the problem either. Why the Vpp isnt 0.087 ?

Comment: Again, you alienated users that can help  you, your scope settings are off,  you have the incorrect v/div and offsets on channels and your channels have incorrect coupling

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/pajrwptl6fbh5fo/check_current_only.rar?dl=0

Comment: @crasic see my new edit post , it has different scope settings is this what you are taking about ?

Comment: Look, I assume you are just getting those value directly from the scope screen, but your scope is doing some vertical offseting, *every* scope does vertical offsets and positions, the key is to read the true value referenced to the 0 position of the channel and not the scope screen.

Comment: @crasic how about now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, let me first say that Proteus ISIS is not the most accurate simulator. It is fast, robust, and friendly, but does a lot of assuming and coarse-granularity calculations (such as the volt meters.)

C18 is coupling the lower leg of the "current source" to ground. Okay, so that CS leg can be considered "AC ground" now[1]. But then C19 and C20 attempt to ground the *other* source leg, after R38.[2] Thus, these capacitors are fighting against each other across the input signal. C18 and C19 are fairly low value, and the frequency is very low, so they only have a minor influence. But C20 is fairly large, and so will "dominate" as ground. The combination of these attenuates the input signal slightly.

[1] Depending on the frequency. Simulation software often only considers the "ideal" properties of components. They do not take into consideration all of the parasitic properties, so can't model accurate results of a cheap electrolytic vs. solid tantalum cap. Due to these real parasitic effects, their AC response is never flat. So in testing, this circuit would be highly influenced by factors outside of the simulation.

[2] 1k/300uF LP filter = 0.53Hz cutoff point, or about -40dB at 50Hz. Luckily the inputs are in differential mode, otherwise very little signal would even make it to the op-amp.

If the AC current source can have one leg grounded, I'd redraw this as a [non-inverting amplifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier_applications#Non-inverting_amplifier), and remove C18-20 and R39. If the "current source" is a current transformer, consider extra precautions for safety. (If the 29 Ohm resistor were to ever fail open, thousands of volts could be generated across it.)

Note that the output after the (12k/12k) voltage divider could be as high as +6.00v if a rail-to-rail op-amp is used. Most 5v microcontrollers will not take kindly to a 6v input. Easy enough to fix, just change the [divider](http://www.raltron.com/cust/tools/voltage_divider.asp) to 16.8k/12k and it can only output 5.00v maximum. (15k and a 2.2k trimpot should work well.)

Also, R44 and C21 form a [7.95kHz low-pass filter](http://sim.okawa-denshi.jp/en/CRtool.php). While not attenuating the output signal measurably at 50Hz, it has little other value. Unless heavy >= 10kHz [EMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_interference) is expected.

Comment: Thank you for the information , I removed C20 and reduced C19 to 25nF and it worked , I can display the exact current flowing the shunt resistor . Previously the current value on lcd  had a 0.5-1.5 mA error . Just for my information , when you say a 0.53Hz cut off at + terminal of opamp , meaning it allow everything below 0.53Hz ? This was the issue all along my 50Hz got attenuated due to this , am I correct ?

Comment: There two CTs cascaded , CT1 is 100A/5A and next CT has  a maximum Ip of 20A and a non uniform conversion factor (Ip / Is) but experimental data suggest if input to CT2 varies between 0-5A then Ip/Is is 1670 , using this information the output of CT2 will vary from 0mA - 3mA . So no harm done. If you want to add something to this , please do so